# Methodists: How to be forgiven of habitual sin?

Tags: sin, forgiveness, methodist

According to Methodist Protestant Christians, if I acknowledge my sin, ask in private prayer for Christ's forgiveness. Am I forgiven?

And what do I do if I'm dealing with a habitual sin that keeps on coming, especially with feelings that because I keep falling, I'm not actually forgiven? How do I get forgiven and how do I feel forgiven? (Also how to I ask for grace to be better?)

Comment: _Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor._